# Build qt5.8 with desktop opengl option (ubuntu)

Tags: qt, ubuntu, opengl, build, desktop

I built the sources of Qt5.8 with the option ./configure -opengl desktop
Then, I did a make and finally sudo make install. Now I changed the .profile file as pointed here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-building.html

But I have a question: How can I start now qt creator ide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're looking for qt creator, which isn't bundled in the qt sources and must be compiled separately, however if you want qt creator alongside with your new qt build, download the qt creator alone and install it, after that open the qt creator, go to Settings -> Build & Run -> Qt Versions , from there you can add new qt versions, just point to qmake which is located in your new qt installation (Probably /usr/local/qt5/bin/qmake) , now add a new kit via Kit's tab and then you can use your newly installed qt with qt creator.